# Group by a column and return multiple aggregates as a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a csv having multiple columns. 
As an example, here is the header and the first 2 rows of the file:

```
ACC;SYM;SumRealPNL;Count;MinAVG;PerLotPNL;SumOneLotPNL;ProfitOnly;ProfitOnlyCount;ProfitOnlyMinAVG;LossOnly;LossOnlyCount;LossOnlyMinAVG;Period;-;P;Q;R;S;Total;U;AS;W;YEAH;Y
31942;EURUSD;4.593,00;17;730;336,47;5.720,00;5.720,00;17;730;0,00;0;0;4;;1;2;0;1;4;A;31942EURUSD1;12;16;18
34887;XAUUSD;16.150,00;7;276;588,43;4.119,00;4.119,00;7;276;0,00;0;0;4;;1;2;0;1;4;A;34887XAUUSD1;12;16;18
```

I load the csv file to a dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_csv('aaaa.csv', header=0, sep=';')
```

I grouped the dataframe by **AS** column:

```
byAS = df.groupby('AS')
```

Now I want to create a new dataframe having the following columns using the DataFrameGroupBy object (byAS):

- AS column
- First value of ACC column
- First value of U column
- Average of PerLotPNL column
- Sum of SumOneLotPNL column
- Sum of Y column

How can I do that?

Comment: Please describe what the original file looks like and what your desired output is. Aggregating the columns with means/sums is straightforward, but it's unclear what the ACC column or U column should be.

Comment: Include the csv file if it's not too big in the question. That makes the problem easier.

Comment: @MYGz  I added a part of the csv file. Is it enough for you to understand the data?

Comment: I edited my question @3novak

Comment: It's still unclear what the desired output is.

Comment: I want to create a dataframe having the AS, ACC, U, Average of PerLotPNL, Sum of SumOneLotPNL, Sum of Y columns using the DataFrameGroupBy object @3novak.

Comment: Your example data has two different values for the `ACC` column: 31942 and 34887. Do you want means? Sums? First? Last? Concatenated strings? Please describe what the output looks like.

Comment: I updated my question @3novak . Is it clear now?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Once you have your dataframe `df` and group on the `AS` column as you have already in your post, you can use the [agg](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) function to obtain the desired output.

```
byAS = df.groupby('AS')

result = byAS.agg({'ACC': 'first',
                   'U': 'first', 
                   'PerLotPNL': np.mean,
                   'SumOneLotPNL': np.sum,
                   'Y': np.sum}).reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: I'm getting pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate.

Comment: That means you have to do some data cleaning on your dataframe because the aggregating functions are encountering nonnumeric data. Check the dtypes of the columns and use [pd.to_numeric()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) where appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @3novak